# ASIC design - combinational logic

Tags: asic

I had an interview a few days back and this was the question they asked me in one of the rounds:

> A mux which gives output `a` when select line is `1` and `b` when it is `0`. The output is represented as `C`. This has to be implemented with `and` and `not` gates only.

I got it almost but was not sure how the output is received finally in combinational ckt. It is a very simple thing I missed here. I gave the select line to an `and` gate and input `a` and the select line and the input `b` through a `not` gate to another `and` gate so I got the output as `A` and `B` but how can we have one output alone? either `a` or `b`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 C = (A and not(S)) or (B and S)
   = not(not(A and not(S)) and not(B and S))
```

Comment: Hey only and gate and not gate. You have used "or"

Comment: I included the first line to show working. The second line is how to do it without the OR.

Comment: Basically it's a question to prove you know Demorgan's laws (often call theorems, but I'm not sure why). I remember it as 'Split the line, change the sign' (Where the line is the bar above showing inversion, and the sign is AND or OR). The next step is to do everything with NAND gates: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=demorgans+theorem

Comment: @AnthonyBlake: I think your answer is slightly wrong. "A when select is 1" and you've got (A and not(S)), which is A when select is 0.

Comment: Ahh OK -- I just copied the equation for a MUX off wikipedia and then applied demorgans laws. I didn't actually check to see if it was around the right way. Also, I vaguely remember that in practice, MUXes are usually implemented with transmission gates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A input 1,
B input 2,
S input select line,
C output,

```
C = (A & S) | (A & ~S);
```

Its simple bro!